# Rendering multiple states one after the other using .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm having some difficulty with rendering using .map. What I'm trying to do is to render the artist name, the song title, and a link to a page where you can find sheet music. I have a separate state for each one of these categories and it looks like this:

```
this.state = {
        currentSearch: "",
        artistName: [],
        songTitle: [],
        tabId: [],
    }
```

Here is my render:

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.props.artist.map((artist, i) =>{
                return(
                    <h3>{artist}</h3>
                )
            })}

            {this.props.title.map((title, i) => {
                return (
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                )
            })}

            {this.props.link.map((link, i) => {
                return (
                    <h3>{link}</h3>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The main problem that I'm having is that the information will display on the page like this:

```
The Beatles
The Beatles
The Beatles
All You Need Is Love
Blackbird
Twist and Shout
www.allyouneedisloveurl.com
www.blackbirdurl.com
www.twistandshouturl.com
```

Is there a way I can map these so that they appear one after the other like this?

```
The Beatles
All You Need Is Love
www.songurl.com
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I see `artistName`, and `songTitle` on `this.state` but then you render `title`, `link` and `artist` from `this.props` - is that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index to render the other data. Try

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.props.artist.map((artist, i) =>{
                return(
                    <div key={i}>
                       <h3>{artist}</h3>
                       <h3>{this.props.title[i]}</h3>
                       <h3>{this.props.link[i]}</h3>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all together in one map like this:

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {
       this.props.artist.map((artist, i) =>{
         return( 
           <div key={i} className="artist">
             <h3>{artist}</h3>
             <h3>{this.props.title[i]}</h3>
             <h3>{this.props.link[i]}</h3>
           </div>
         )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```